# Bot Authenticate user Seamlessly in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Can the Bot Authenticate user Seamlessly in Microsoft Teams by using Microsoft Graph?
For Example,
The user no need to click Sign in again.

I had look so many example in Microsoft Docs, still does not had any example.

I had go through the sample code, that always ask the user to Sign-in.

Answer (score 1):

The Teams team has mentioned that they are working on Single-Sign-On (SSO) for Bots like there is for Tabs, but I don't know if it's implemented yet. In the meantime, you'll need to implement authentication in your bot, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample).